# SCSS: Why Parent Child selector syntax does not apply styles?

Tags: css, sass

Markup:

```
<div class="form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="text-field">
      /* I want to apply styles for this div */
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`scss` styles:

```
.form {
  &-row {

    // WHY this doesn't work
    .text-field {
      width: 20%;
    }

    // WHY this doesn't work
    div.text-field {
      width: 20%;
    }

    // WHY this doesn't work
    & .text-field {
      width: 20%;
    }


    // This works. I don't want this syntax.
    div[class^='text-field'] {
      width: 20%;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All of those options work. https://jsfiddle.net/Lbwdk92y/1/ - uncomment the background colours to test.

Comment: Are you compiling your SASS correctly? All options should work except the third one https://jsfiddle.net/vybL1sc7/1/

Comment: @Turnip, No they don't in my code! I wouldn't ask if they did.

Comment: The code you have provided works fine so the problem is elsewhere. What have you done to debug this? Is the SCSS actually being compiled? What does the compiled CSS look like? It is difficult for anybody to answer your question when you have only provided a working code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

all options are  work correctly...
i just check using background color :

```
.form {
    &-row {

        // WHY this doesn't work
        .text-field {
            width           : 20%;
            background-color: red;
        }

        // WHY this doesn't work
        div.text-field {
            width           : 20%;
            background-color: red;
        }

        // WHY this doesn't work
        & .text-field {
            width           : 20%;
            background-color: red;
        }


        // This works. I don't want this syntax.
        div[class^='text-field'] {
            width           : 20%;
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
}
```